# variable passed to sql from shell is not working

Tags: sql, bash, shell, awk, oracle11g

My code is:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat tmp_ts.log | awk ' {print $8}'
lookup=$8
sqlplus -s "sys/Orcl1234 as sysdba" << EOF
SELECT tablespace_name FROM dba_tablespaces WHERE tablespace_name='$lookup';
exit;
EOF
```

**and my output is:**

```
IAM_OIM
no rows selected
```

In this variable lookup I have passed to select statement but it's not working.

My end result should be with select statement. See below the output of select query:

See below:

[image]

My end result should be this but that variable is not working in select statement.

Comment: You are confusing `awk`’s `$8` with rhe shell’s `$8`. The first line of your script prints the 8th field of the rows in `tmp_ts.log` but it is never used afterwards and `lookup` ends up empty. Please post some eexample rows from `tmp_ts.log` and the corresponding expected output.

Comment: Thanks Dario,, My rows in tmp_ts.log file is -> "Alert: Running out of space in tablespace- IAM_OIM" so its fetching 8th field.. and later i assigned that to lookup ... but why lookup is not taking that field

Comment: any suggestions regarding??? I want to send that 8th field keyword to sql

Comment: how to use that 8th field printed keyword and i want to use that keyword in select statement

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
lookup="$(awk '/tablespace/{print $8;exit}' tmp_ts.log)"
echo "Querying database with lookup = $lookup"
sqlplus -s "sys/Orcl1234 as sysdba" <<EOF
SELECT tablespace_name FROM dba_tablespaces WHERE tablespace_name='$lookup';
exit;
EOF
```

You have to use `awk`'s output to set `lookup`. The shell knows nothing about the `$8` which was set in `awk`. Also, I have ensured that `awk` exits after the first matching line, so that there is no risk of returning multiple values, or simply empty lines as it did in your version.

Answer (score 0):

You can fill lookup with a command like `awk`, `sed` or `cut`.

```
lookup=$(cut -d" "  -f8 tmp_ts.log)
```

You should add some checks, like @Dario did (with an exit after the first match and only converting lines with `tablespace`, but what to do when no lines match?).

When you don't add the checks you can skip setting the `$lookup`:

```
sqlplus -s "sys/Orcl1234 as sysdba" << EOF
SELECT tablespace_name FROM dba_tablespaces
 WHERE tablespace_name='$(sed 's/.*tablespace- //' tmp_ts.log)';
exit;
EOF
```